# How can I create a new column in a DataFrame that shows patterns in a different column?

Tags: python, pandas

My original CSV file looks like this

```
1, 9
2, 8
3, 9
14, 7
15, 6
19, 8
20, 9
21, 3
```

I grouped the table for continuous integers in column A with

```
for grp, val in df.groupby((df.diff()-1).fillna(0).cumsum().index1):
print(val)
```

Resulting table:

```
    A   B
1   1   9
2   2   8
3   3   9
    A   B
14  14  7
15  15  6
    A   B
19  19  8
20  20  9
21  21  3
```

In practice the B values are very long ID numbers, but insignificant as numbers. How can I create a new column C that will show patterns in each of the three groups by assigning a simple value to each ID, and the same simple value for each duplicate in a group?

Desired output:

```
    A   B   C
1   1   9   1
2   2   8   2
3   3   9   1
    A   B   C
14  14  7   1
15  15  6   2
    A   B   C
19  19  8   1
20  20  9   2
21  21  3   3
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are close

```
df['C']=df.groupby((df.A.diff()-1).fillna(0).cumsum()).B.apply(lambda x : pd.Series(pd.factorize(x)[0]+1)).values
df
Out[105]: 
    A  B  C
0   1  9  1
1   2  8  2
2   3  9  1
3  14  7  1
4  15  6  2
5  19  8  1
6  20  9  2
7  21  3  3
```

Or using category

```
df['C']=df.groupby((df.A.diff()-1).fillna(0).cumsum()).B.apply(lambda x : x.astype('category').cat.codes+1).values
df
Out[110]: 
    A  B  C
0   1  9  2
1   2  8  1
2   3  9  2
3  14  7  2
4  15  6  1
5  19  8  2
6  20  9  3
7  21  3  1
```

if you need for loop

```
for x,df1 in df.groupby((df.A.diff()-1).fillna(0).cumsum()):

    print(df1.assign(C=pd.factorize(df1.B)[0]+1))


   A  B  C
0  1  9  1
1  2  8  2
2  3  9  1
    A  B  C
3  14  7  1
4  15  6  2
    A  B  C
5  19  8  1
6  20  9  2
7  21  3  3
```

Answer (score 1):

Let's try:

```
df.columns = ['A','B']

g = df.groupby(df.A.diff().ne(1).cumsum())
df['C'] = g['B'].transform(lambda x: pd.factorize(x)[0] + 1)

for n,g in g:
    print(g)
```

Output:

```
   A  B  C
0  1  9  1
1  2  8  2
2  3  9  1
    A  B  C
3  14  7  1
4  15  6  2
    A  B  C
5  19  8  1
6  20  9  2
7  21  3  3
```

Answer (score 0):

Try `withColumn` function that will add a new column to the dataframe and you may assign an index value.